# Simpliest ancestor for a clickable, hand-drawn component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, graphics, components, uicomponents

I am creating a component that will be a large plus or a large minus. I don't want to use a bitmap because even I can draw this using the Graphics class, but the component must be clickable (the Shape class is not).

It will be part of an item renderer, so I want it to be as light-weight as possible. UIComponent does not seem to sent CLICK messages.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: I don't recommend you to hand-draw the component, it may damage your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a Sprite object and drawing the minus and plus arrows to its graphics object. You'll then have to addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someFunction); in its constructor or wherever else you'll need it.

You may also want to set cacheAsBitmap to true at that point, so that it's not redrawn every frame.

---

EDIT: Per @jeremynealbrown you have to use the SpriteAsset class if you are working in Flex, apparently. Very similar, but another 2 levels of abstraction are added.

Comment: Sprite is the highest class that you can access both the graphics object and the MouseEvent.CLICK event.

Comment: A Sprite is essentially the same thing as a MovieClip, but without the timeline. A Sprite is higher in the heirarchy than a MovieClip, so it will be more lightweight.

Comment: I guess it's how you look at it, higher-lower

Comment: True, I generally look at the base class as being at the top and everything else comes down from it. Not sure why...

Comment: Neither will work with the Flex framework, you will need to use SpriteAsset or MovieClipAsset.

Answer (score 1):

If you look here:
[UIComponent Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/core/UIComponent.html)

You will see that UIComponent has InteractiveObject in its inheritance path.  InteractiveObject is the class that adds mouse event functionality.

Answer (score 1):

UIComponent will actually dispatch click events. However, if there is no content drawn to the graphics, the UIComponent will have no area that can be clicked. If the plus or minus icon you draw is too small to reliably catch mouse activities, then draw a fully-transparent rectangle to increase the hit area.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to reply :)